# Changing the opacity from 0.0 0.1 .. to 1.0 to create an animation effect

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to change the opacity of my frame from 0 to 10 (0.0,0.1,0.2..1.0) so it will create an animation effect.

I tried this code at the end of the constructor but it produce only the last value of the opacity:

```
for(float k=0;k<=10;k++)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        setOpacity(k/10);
    }
```

Comment: Try `setOpacity(k/10.0);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing is single threaded. Calling `Thread.sleep` in the `EDT` prevents `UI` updates. Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

Comment: To suspend it, you can call the `stop()` method.

Answer (score 0):

When the animation is needed to initialize set some boolean variable to true, and then in the render function check if the boolean variable is true, and if it is, add .1, and when it reaches one set the boolean variable back to false.